# Why is Scala Source.fromURL slower than Apaches IOUtils?

Tags: java, scala, io

I am trying to figure it out if there is a faster way to get the content from a URL Using Scala. Using Apache `IOUtils` I am able to get the content faster than `Source.fromURL` in Scala. Here is the code from both:

Using Java:

```
    try {
        tmp=IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://gizmodo.com"));
        tmp=tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf("360\" title=")+12);
        tmp=tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf("\""));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Using Scala:

```
  val gizmodoPageLines = Source.fromURL("http://gizmodo.com").getLines.mkString("\n")
  val pos=gizmodoPageLines.indexOf("360\" title=")
  var tmp=gizmodoPageLines.substring(pos+12)
  tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf("\""))
```

In Java it takes around: 155899 ns

In Scala : 343880 ns

Why is the Scala code so slow?

Comment: It's seriously taking you hundreds of seconds to pull down the front page content of gizmodo.com?

Comment: Have you tried [scala-io](http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io-doc/0.4.1/index.html#!/performance/Class-scalax.io.perf.channel.input.SmallMediumSetsFromFileReadableByteChannelTest_Input-byteArray)? There is some good performance data on that site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in your first you're reading from a buffer, while in your second you're reading line by line.

Source.getLines is not intended as a silver bullet replacement for IOUtils or whatever other library, it's intended to read line by line. You can perfectly use IOUtils in Scala.

Comment: More precisely: Source.fromURL does use a Buffer, but getLines outputs Strings that you then re-concatenate into one single String with mkString, while IOUtils.toString copies much larger chuncks.

Comment: Regarding your figures and the above comment regarding your internet connection, did you forget to mention that you iterated several thousands of times?

Comment: +1 for the comment that you can use IOUtils in Scala: a proven, reliable, optimized library. Scala Source.fromURL.getLines would make sense if you were to map a complex lambda to process lines immutabily

Comment: Is there a way to read the full buffer like IOUtils instead of using getLines?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at how slow your connection is (between 2 and 6 minutes to get gizmodo), you may find that the reading speed between Scala and Java is not the problem, but rather an unreliable internet connection. If you really want to test speed differences, then try serving a file from a local server so that you scrap internet connection speed from the equation.

Lastly, for an advanced HTTP client, I would look at [Spray HTTP Client](http://spray.io/documentation/spray-can/examples). Spray is a really nice non-blocking (using Actors) HTTP toolset.

Comment: Or, if you want a straighforward blocking HTTP client API, there is http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client, which is blocking by default but uses futures for non-blocking requests. (This is my own API).